# rails 7 and bootstrap 5.2.3 with importmaps javascript won't work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-5, import-maps

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, I checked also most other similar questions on Stack Overflow, but nothing seem to work for me.

I'm trying to get bootstrap 5.2.3 javascript to work to get a dropdown menu. I'm trying to do this with using importmaps, which looks like the easiest way (I tried also with esbuild with no success).

here's my import maps (bootstrap comes from jsdelivr as I understand the version on yarn has troubles with popper):

```
pin 'application', preload: true
pin '@hotwired/turbo-rails', to: 'turbo.min.js', preload: true
pin '@hotwired/stimulus', to: 'stimulus.min.js', preload: true
pin '@hotwired/stimulus-loading', to: 'stimulus-loading.js', preload: true
pin_all_from 'app/javascript/controllers', under: 'controllers'
pin "bootstrap", to: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.js"
pin "@popperjs/core", to: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/lib/index.js"
```

here's my `app/javascript/application.js`:

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
import "popper"
import "bootstrap"
```

here's my relevant part from `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
  <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
  <% if Rails.env.development? %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "hotwire-livereload", defer: true %>
```

here's my `app/assets/config/manifest.js`

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
//= link_tree ../../javascript .js
```

here's the relevant html header as generated by this configuration:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/application-340caa07ce1bbb3e424a11977f38b20d7ad5bcd57480d126430e8962eb772287.css" data-turbo-track="reload">
  <script type="importmap" data-turbo-track="reload">{
  "imports": {
    "application": "/assets/application-43b3188fdbcd45d694dc59d1f446d56b6a7895097320f451e1f8b34080dfcd63.js",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "/assets/turbo.min-96cbf52c71021ba210235aaeec4720012d2c1df7d2dab3770cfa49eea3bb09da.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "/assets/stimulus.min-900648768bd96f3faeba359cf33c1bd01ca424ca4d2d05f36a5d8345112ae93c.js",
    "@hotwired/stimulus-loading": "/assets/stimulus-loading-1fc59770fb1654500044afd3f5f6d7d00800e5be36746d55b94a2963a7a228aa.js",
    "bootstrap": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.js",
    "@popperjs/core": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/lib/index.js",
    "controllers/application": "/assets/controllers/application-368d98631bccbf2349e0d4f8269afb3fe9625118341966de054759d96ea86c7e.js",
    "controllers/current_link_controller": "/assets/controllers/current_link_controller-370b5b9f12a48b3c3c34f79e6d2782d26737770d0459437000dd110a50aead36.js",
    "controllers": "/assets/controllers/index-2db729dddcc5b979110e98de4b6720f83f91a123172e87281d5a58410fc43806.js"
  }
}</script>
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/application-43b3188fdbcd45d694dc59d1f446d56b6a7895097320f451e1f8b34080dfcd63.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/turbo.min-96cbf52c71021ba210235aaeec4720012d2c1df7d2dab3770cfa49eea3bb09da.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/stimulus.min-900648768bd96f3faeba359cf33c1bd01ca424ca4d2d05f36a5d8345112ae93c.js">
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/stimulus-loading-1fc59770fb1654500044afd3f5f6d7d00800e5be36746d55b94a2963a7a228aa.js">
<script src="/assets/es-module-shims.min-606ae9c3279013fe751cee30f719a592f759e705edb66496812f3d9dbce3d850.js" async="async" data-turbo-track="reload"></script>
<script type="module">import "application"</script>
  <script src="/assets/hotwire-livereload-69f109e9f29dd4f334a14c739a16f66d96595dcede55037f287ea8712288c0ae.js" defer="defer"></script>
```

my gemfile contains:

```
# Use Sass to process CSS
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 5.2.3'
gem 'sassc-rails', '2.1.2'
```

I also don't understand why bootstrap and popper seem to be bundled in the application.css, rather than being listed in the `<link rel....>` includes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using importmaps to to get the Bootstrap you are only getting javascript part. For CSS you will need to download and put it in your stylesheets folder or vendor.

Here is the example:

in `vendor/stylesheets/bootstrap` you download all css files.

in your `importmaps.rb` you will have something like:

```
pin "application"
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin "@popperjs/core", to: "https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/esm/index.js"
pin "bootstrap"
```

in your `application.js` you import like this:

```
// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
import "@popperjs/core"
import "bootstrap"
```

and then in your `application.sass.scss` you will import css from vendor:

```
// Entry point for your Sass build
@import "../../../vendor/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss";
```

or different path if the Bootstrap is for example in your `app/stylesheets`.